# "Ambiguous reference to member 'count' " Error

Tags: ios, swift, firebase

I'm not that much of a pro in using swift..but i've been trying to create an social media app using firebase as backend. But I am stuck in this one part where the data gets stored in an Array..but when . i call the array I keep getting the "Ambiguous reference to member 'count' " error and I have tried many ways to fix this but end up unsuccessful every time

```
var posts = [AnyObject?]()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

 }

 func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell: HomeViewTableViewCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "HomeViewTableViewCell", for: indexPath) as! HomeViewTableViewCell

    let post = (posts[(self.posts.count - 1) - indexPath.row] as AnyObject).value["text"] as! String  //**Ambiguous reference to member 'count'

    cell.configure(nil,NameText:self.loggedInUserData!.value["NameText"] as! String, TitleText:self.loggedInUserData!.value["TitleText"] as! String, post:post)

    return cell
}
```

Please help!

Actually trying this tutorial out in Youtube...So if full code required, This is the YouTube link:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BeZ3i7-gaok&list=PLy9JCsy2u97kro0jXbXrPFmT-DQVAmNW0&index=4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you might want to use value(forKey:) here

```
let post = (posts[(self.posts.count - 1) - indexPath.row] as AnyObject).value(forKey: "text")
```